# Grails sort params

Tags: sorting, grails, extjs4

I am using ExtJS4 library to show a grid of paged data served by a Grails controller and returned as JSON. 
One of the fields is a calculated field that I cannot pass back to the database for a query ... because it's calculated. What is a good solution to implement for this type of column sort request? Other columns I just pass back to the query through : list(params)

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a list, you can use this.

```
   def a = [5,3,4,2,1]
    //for asc
     a.sort{+it}
    //for des
     a.sort{-it}
```

Comment: thanks i'll try this, but i need to differentiate on the column that's being sorted on. right now i just let the database do the sorting for me.